# Команда Send не выводит многозначные числа

Tags: autohotkey

Хотел написать простенький скрипт для быстрой нумерации. По задумке он должен записывать в столбик числа от 1 до указанного в InputBox`е. Всё происходит как нужно до того момента пока счетчик доходит до 10, после чего скрипт просто не вписывает двузначные числа.

```
InputBox,a, Сколько вводим?, число плиз,50,80
b:=0
Loop {
b:=b+1
sleep, 300
if (b>1)
Send {Down}
sleep, 300
Send {Backspace}
sleep, 300
Send {%b%}
sleep, 300
if (a=b)
break
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, Send посылает нажатие клавиши. Если вам нужно послать 10, то это уже два нажатия. На клавиатуре просто нет такой кнопки "10".

Comment: Существует ли в ahk команда, которая может вводить сразу строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputBox, a, Сколько вводим?, число плиз, 50, 80
b = 0
Loop {
    b += 1
    sleep, 300
    if (b > 1){
        SendInput, %b%
        sleep, 300
        if b < 10
            SendInput, {Backspace}
        else
            SendInput, {Backspace 2}
        sleep, 300
    }
    if (a = b)
        break
}
```

Так должно работать и с двухзначными числами.

> Существует ли в ahk команда, которая может вводить сразу строки?

```
SendInput {Raw}Длинная последовательность символов, посылаемая без интерпретации.
```

Comment: Спасибо, через SendInput, %b% работает. До этого пробовал SendInput {%b%}, не работало

Comment: @DmytroYurkevich, в фигурных скобках имитируется нажатие клавиши клавиатуры, поэтому и посылался только первый символ двузначного числа, как писал insolor. А без них посылается значение переменной. как-то так.